# About model first EF4 development

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I just tried that out, and I also found that If I changed EF model and want to regenerate the database from model , all existing data in database will lost.

Is there any way to fix that, as this always happens during the development.

Comment: Yes, the designer really ought to offer a change-script option. Maybe next version.

Comment: Presumably you aren't applying the designer script to your production database? If not you can create a new database schema (for test/development) and then when you are happy with it use a schema update tool (e.g. Red Gate's SQL Compare) to apply the schema to your production database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Entity Designer Database generation powerpack
it's a visual studio add on from microsoft, which let's you modify your db schema without wiping your data.

Answer (score 0):

James Gaunt basically nailed it - generate the schema in a new database and use schema update tools. You don't necessarily need to buy anything there are schema and data compare and migrate tools in Visual Studio under the "Data" Menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try Devart [Entity Developer](http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/). We offer the database synchronization functionality for Entity Framework and LINQ to SQL models, see [this article](http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/model-first.html) for details.